# Sendmail is refusing connection after configuring SMTP relay

Tags: sendmail

I'm setting up sendmail on my home computer to use with my webserver. I've set it to use my SMTP server provided by my hosting company.

If I use the following command, it **works**

```
sendmail -Am -t -v
```

and then I enter the to and from emails.

---

But if I try the following, it **does not work**.

```
sendmail -v name@mydomain.com < test.txt
```

The TO email is the same as in the earlier command, but in this case I haven't specified a FROM e-mail, which I think is the problem.

My guess is that it's sending the mail from user@localhost causing the smtp server to reject it. If so, how do I make it send from user@mydomain.com?

Comment: Sendmail log output would help. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that if your home machine just needs to send email out and not receive it that you set up [msmtp](http://msmtp.sourceforge.net/) instead.  It provides all the features you need for sending mail without doing any inbound processing.  Here's a sample `.msmtprc`:

> host smtp.example.com
>   user test
>   password testpass
>   from test@example.com
>   auth login

with that, my user can send mail that appears to come from `example.com`. If your webserver user needs to send mail you can configure this for that user.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll give it a try next time. I already got my sendmail to work. It was a silly configuration mistake on my part. The daemon was disabled.

My reason to use sendmail was to make it identical to the configurating on my VPS where I'll be moving all my files to after I finish development. Selected as the best answer. Thanks

Comment: well darn, guess I just took to long to post my answer below.  care to give my suggestion a whirl?

Comment: Patrick's suggestion makes more sense than mine, if you're already using sendmail.

Comment: feel free to bump me up a point ;).

Comment: Patrick I've given you credit where credit is due, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to pull this off by editing your `/etc/mail/sendmail.cf` file

```
#vi /etc/mail/sendmail.cf
```

add

```
FEATURE(`genericstable',`hash -o /etc/mail/genericstable.db')dnl
GENERICS_DOMAIN_FILE(`/etc/mail/generics-domains')dnl
```

next

```
#vi /etc/mail/genericstable
```

add

```
username   anotherusername@domain.com
```

So you could make it look like apache or root sent the email as someone else

```
apache     anotherusername@mydomain.com
root       anotherusername-2@mydomain.com
```

next

```
#vi /etc/mail/generics-domains
```

add

```
subdomain.mydomain.com
mydomain.com
```

next generate new configs and restart sendmail

```
#makemap -r hash genericstable.db < genericstable
#m4 sendmail.mc > sendmail.cf
#/etc/init.d/sendmail restart
```

Now you should be able to send out your email as root or apache or whoever you defined above and it will show up in your inbox as coming from them.

Try out while logged in as root or apache process

```
#echo "test" | sendmail bubba@mydomain.com
```

You should find that the sender was anotherusername or anotherusername-2